# cURL 404 Error - URL encoding with SharePoint URL

Tags: linux, curl, url, api

I am trying to connect to a SharePoint URL and pull the data in the form of a `.json` file. My URL looks like this:

```
.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('titles list')/items
```

If I give the URL as it is without any encoding, it fails with a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error. I tried using `-G` and `--data-urlencode` as follows:

```
curl -v -G -L --ntlm --user user:password -H 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' ".../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle" --data-urlencode "('titles list')" -d "/items"
```

Doing this converts my URL to `.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle?%28%27titles%20list%27%29&/items`

But it fails with `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` since using `-G` will append a `?` and `&` to the URL. Having the `?` and `&` present will give me a different URL and hence the `404 not found` error.

I have no issues accessing other end points such as `../_api/web/lists` since - I believe - there is no need to encode this URL?

How do I properly encode my URL and get the data without any errors?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue by directly using encoded characters in the URL of the `cURL` command.

Here is an example:

```
curl -v -L --ntlm --user user:password -H 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' ".../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle%28%27titles%20list%27%29/items"
```